# Paypal Sandbox showing error

Tags: paypal

Paypal sandbox is showing error after login when click on Continue button.

```
Error: no template specified
```

at engine (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/adaro/lib/engine.js:90:29)
 at View.proto.render (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/engine-munger/lib/expressView.js:45:9)
 at tryRender (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:639:10)
 at EventEmitter.render (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:591:3)
 at ServerResponse.render (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:960:7)
 at ServerResponse.res.render (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/pplogger/index.js:242:20)
 at ServerResponse._analytics.res.render (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/analytics-paypal/lib/node-analytics.js:204:16)
 at ServerResponse.res.render (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/monitor-paypal/lib/taniwha.js:182:25)
 at handle500 (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/controllers/middleware/responses.js:211:7)
 at handle500 (:1:75)
 at Layer.handle_error (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
 at trim_prefix (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:310:13)
 at /x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
 at Function.process_params (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
 at next (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
 at logErrors (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/controllers/middleware/responses.js:331:5)
 at logErrors (:1:75)
 at Layer.handle_error (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
 at trim_prefix (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:310:13)
 at /x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
 at Function.process_params (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
 at next (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
 at handleError (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/controllers/middleware/responses.js:174:4)
 at handleError (:1:77)
 at Layer.handle_error (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
 at trim_prefix (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:310:13)
 at /x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
 at Function.process_params (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
 at next (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
 at Layer.handle_error (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:67:12)
 at trim_prefix (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:310:13)
 at /x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
 at Function.process_params (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
 at Object.next (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
 at Object. (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:618:15)
 at Object. (/x/ebay/cronus/software/service_nodes/.ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28.unifiedloginnodeweb-app__ENVaqqittlg2x28-SLCA-CL5c6jxi7nyl-10.72.136.62/installed-packages/unifiedloginnodeweb/0.4.46_20160921123512280.unx/cronus/scripts/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:188:31)
 at Object.immediate._onImmediate (timers.js:381:16)
 at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:363:15)

Comment: Just googled your thread. I've got something similar when I try to log in. Hopefully they will fix it soon.

Comment: I received the same error when tried to access the login page at `sandbox.paypal.com`. Hope this to be fixed soon... Also deleted cookies etc but no help, still same error!

Comment: I also got the same error.

Comment: Today the page is completely down. Seriously, I'm wondering what the f*$# the programmers at Paypal are doing. I have to finish an important project but every 2 to 3 days the page has problems. How can one work / debug / do changes in a live environment?!  Unbelievable...