# Paypal login "Error: no template specified at engine"

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am following the example here:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/button-js-builder/

with the javascript:

```
paypal.use( ['login'], function (login) {
  login.render ({
    "appid":"myAppID",
    "scopes":"profile email address phone https://uri.paypal.com/services/paypalattributes",
    "containerid":"lippButton",
    "locale":"en-us",
    "returnurl":"myReturnUrl"
  });
});
```

and get the following error when I click on the log in button. Another window pops up with the error:

> Error: no template specified at engine

Is this on their end? Or is it some credential related error?

Comment: There is also a question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676061/paypal-sandbox-showing-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting the same thing and mine was working last night.  My guess is that they're doing (or did) some sort of maintenance.

Comment: Its working now, it was indeed maintenance on their end.